# BeagleBone Black Wireless - No space left on device

Tags: linux, debian, logs, disk-usage, beagleboneblack

I am a newcomer to this device and I was surprised to see 'No space left on device' today after having not installed too much on it.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            216M     0  216M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  8.7M   40M  18% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p1  3.5G  3.3G     0 100% /
tmpfs           243M     0  243M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           243M     0  243M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000

sudo du -s -k /*
[sudo] password for debian: 
4       /bbb-uEnv.txt
6664    /bin
33104   /boot
0       /dev
5988    /etc
260592  /home
4       /ID.txt
270064  /lib
16      /lost+found
4       /media
4       /mnt
4       /nfs-uEnv.txt
186408  /opt
du: cannot access '/proc/28493': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28532': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28533/task/28533/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28533/task/28533/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28533/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28533/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28554': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28557': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28558': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28560': No such file or directory
0       /proc
15480   /root
8824    /run
6480    /sbin
4       /srv
0       /sys
56      /tmp

du -s -k /var/log/*
2212976 /usr
413268  /var

du -s -k /var/log/*
0   /var/log/alternatives.log
40  /var/log/alternatives.log.1
216136  /var/log/apache2
84  /var/log/apt
792 /var/log/auth.log
144 /var/log/auth.log.1
104 /var/log/bootstrap.log
0   /var/log/btmp
4   /var/log/btmp.1
4824    /var/log/daemon.log
1892    /var/log/daemon.log.1
8   /var/log/debug
28  /var/log/debug.1
0   /var/log/dpkg.log
676 /var/log/dpkg.log.1
24  /var/log/faillog
4   /var/log/fontconfig.log
204 /var/log/kern.log
948 /var/log/kern.log.1
288 /var/log/lastlog
du: cannot read directory '/var/log/lightdm': Permission denied
4   /var/log/lightdm
1244    /var/log/messages
924 /var/log/messages.1
4   /var/log/roboticscape
5772    /var/log/syslog
200 /var/log/syslog.1
20  /var/log/syslog.2.gz
56  /var/log/syslog.3.gz
4   /var/log/syslog.4.gz
376 /var/log/syslog.5.gz
1048    /var/log/user.log
24  /var/log/user.log.1
792 /var/log/wtmp
140 /var/log/wtmp.1
0   /var/log/xinput_calibrator.pointercal.log
12  /var/log/Xorg.0.log
16  /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
```

By running `sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100M`, I discovered that the Apache log file is very large:

```
du /var/log/apache2/access.log.1
130784  /var/log/apache2/access.log.1
```

If this is indeed the cause, how can I prevent this ever happening again? I need my device to work consistently.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable and turn off the Apache logging just direct the log entries  `customlog` and `errorlog` to `/dev/null` in the `.conf` file(s) for your site, probably inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

Alternatively, if you wish to still keep *some* logging, you could set up a cron job that periodically cleans out the log files.